# Get OrderTotal by hourly for current date gives subquery error :

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL query which presently gives hourly order data for current the date. Here I need to count order by following case when condition, if I add this I am getting sub-query error after 11:00 AM, Please anybody help me out to solve problem.

Following SQL query on which I am performing:

```
DECLARE  @intervalMinutes int = 60
DECLARE  @schedule table (
        myId int primary key identity,
        startTime time,
        endTime time
)

DECLARE @startTime time= '12:00:00 AM'; 
DECLARE @endTime time='11:00:00 PM';

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @startTime st
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,@intervalMinutes,st) 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE st < DATEADD(MINUTE,@intervalMinutes,st) 

)
INSERT INTO @schedule(startTime,endTime)
SELECT st, DATEADD(MINUTE,@intervalMinutes,st)FROM cte 

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), startTime, 100) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),  endTime , 100)  AS TimeSlots,
ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.isAfterDiscount,0) != 0 THEN ((O.SubTotal - Total_Discount) + O.Total_Tax)
                ELSE ((O.SubTotal + O.Total_Tax) - Total_Discount)
                END AS OrderTotal FROM [dbo].[Order] AS O WHERE O.Order_Status='COMPLETED' AND 
(O.CreatedDate >= CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETUTCDATE(),101)  + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), startTime, 108) as datetime)) 
AND (O.CreatedDate <= CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETUTCDATE(),101)  + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), REPLACE(endTime,'00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999'), 108) as datetime))),0)   AS TotalSales
FROM @schedule
```

The following error comes while execute query:

[image: following error comes while execute query]

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The following query results which I need to display:

[image: following query results which I need to display]

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Code, errors and data should all be displayed as formatted text - not images. I can't read the error on the image.

Comment: I have added error text

Comment: You can remove the image then - and make the question easier to read. And please do the same to the table of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, you have got many values comes from Order table subquery. You have to apply SUM aggregate function to sum over the sales amount from order table.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startTime, 100) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), endTime, 100) AS TimeSlots
    ,ISNULL((
            SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.isAfterDiscount, 0) != 0 THEN ((O.SubTotal - Total_Discount) + O.Total_Tax) ELSE ((O.SubTotal + O.Total_Tax) - Total_Discount) END) AS OrderTotal
            FROM [dbo].[Order] AS O
            WHERE O.Order_Status = 'COMPLETED'
                AND (O.CreatedDate >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETUTCDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), startTime, 108) AS DATETIME))
                AND (O.CreatedDate <= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETUTCDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), REPLACE(endTime, '00:00:00.000', '23:59:59.999'), 108) AS DATETIME))
            ), 0) AS TotalSales
FROM @schedule
```

Comment: Thank you very much . it works for me for above condition

Comment: But I add below Case when condition its not working it gives subquery error.
SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.isAfterDiscount, 0) != 0 THEN        CASE WHEN O.Order_Status='RETURN' THEN ((O.SubTotal - O.Total_Discount) + O.Total_Tax) ELSE (((O.SubTotal - ISNULL(R.SubTotal,0)) - (O.Total_Discount - ISNULL(R.Total_Discount,0))) + (O.Total_Tax- ISNULL(R.Total_Tax,0)))END
ELSE CASE WHEN  O.Order_Status='RETURN' THEN ((O.SubTotal + O.Total_Tax) - O.Total_Discount) ELSE(((O.SubTotal - ISNULL(R.SubTotal,0)) + (O.Total_Tax - ISNULL(R.Total_Tax,0))) - (O.Total_Discount - ISNULL(R.Total_Discount,0)))END
END)

Comment: Thanks it works for me now with above condition also